# necesito compara datos de un texto con palabras positivas y negativas

Tags: c++

el proyecto consiste en leer un documente que tienen palabras positivas y negativas
debes comparar las palabras del diccionario de positivas y negativas con el documento
contabiliza las palabras comunes del documento con tus palabras positivas y negativas
y despues compara la cantidad de palabras positivas y negativas dentro de un vector.
ahora al comparar el que sea mayor debe indicar que el texto es positivo o negativo

leer un documento
crear un vector con palabras positivas
crear un vector con palabras negativas
encontrar las palabras del documento con las palabras positivas y negativas
contabilizar por separado las palabras positivas y negativas
guardar esas palabras positivas y negativas cada en un vector separado
si el resultado de la comparacion es positiva o negativa debe mostrarlo en el mensaje

este es mi codigo de momento pude leer el archivo pero, no se como proceder para comparar el archivo con el texto

y pense en que debo pasar el texto al vector, palabra por palabra, pero de ahi veo que no tiene sentido, ya que para que leería el archivo de texto
tengo dudas en cuanto al desarrollo , favor si me pueden ayudar

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void lectura();

int main(){

 string posit[]={encantaría ,laborar ,sueños}; // vector positivas
 string negat[]={doloroso ,abandonar,necesidad,gastos}; // vector negativas

 string lectura[]={encantaría, laborar, organización, esté, ligada, estudio, oferta, laboral, general, mercado, Ahora, pienso, llevar, cursos, Gestión, Empresarial, porque, dado, cuenta, puedo, vivir, sueños, doloroso, sentir, debo, abandonar, gusta, solo, necesidad, poder, cubrir, gastos};

lectura();
}

void lectura(){
    ifstream leer; // se crea para poder el archivo .txt
    string texto; //creamos esta variable para poder guardar aqui todo lo que leamos
    leer.open("textoleer.txt",ios::in); //abrimos el archivo modo lectura
    if(leer.fail()){
        cout<<"no se puedo abrir el texto";
        exit(1);
    }
    while(!leer.eof()){  // mientras no sea el final de leer
        getline(leer,texto); // copiamos todo lo que abra leer, a la variable texto
        cout<<texto<<endl;
    }
    leer.close(); // cerramos el archivo
}**
```

Comment: Siendo específicos, cuál es la pregunta ¿?

Comment: No se como hacer para comparar el archivo con las palabras positivas o negativas   , como comparo el texto con las palabras positivas y negativas ?

Answer (score 0):

> como comparo el texto con las palabras positivas y negativas ?

Para poder comparar las palabras del texto con las que hay en las listas lo primero que tienes que hacer es leer el fichero... palabra por palabra

```
while( true )
{
  std::string palabra;
  leer >> palabra;
  if( leer.eof() )
    break;
}
```

Nota que la comprobación del final de fichero se hace **después** del intento de lectura. Esto se hace así porque el flag de EOF no se activa hasta que no se ha realizado una lectura que intente llegar más allá del fin del archivo.

Una vez que tienes la palabra, el siguiente paso es ver si existe en una de las dos listas:

```
int totalPositivas = 0;
for( std::string const& positiva : posit )
{
  if( positiva == palabra )
  {
    totalPositivas++;
    break;
  }
}
```

Y lo mismo para las negativas

El código final quedaría así:

```
int totalPositivas = 0;
while( true )
{
  std::string palabra;
  leer >> palabra;
  if( leer.eof() )
    break;

  for( std::string const& positiva : posit )
  {
    if( positiva == palabra )
    {
      totalPositivas++;
      break;
    }
  }
}

std::cout << "Total palabras positivas: " << totalPositivas << '\n';
```

Comment: Gracias lo trabajare en el código, si tengo alguna, quizá te haga mas consultas, gracias de verdad